# How to write custom attributes (ATTRS{attribute_name} to a USB-Device?

Tags: bash, hardware, missing-data, serial-number

I have 2 identical devices which I want to differentiate using udev rules.

However, after executing the following for the devices, I have found out that the Serial Number is **missing** from the given hardware for 1 device.

For every device this number should be unique and visible.

When the good one only is connected it shows the Serial Number,

```
$ udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0) | grep -i Serial
ATTRS{serial}=="XXXXXXXX"
```

When the faulty one only is connected it does not show serial number.

```
$ udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB1) | grep -i Serial

$
```

When the good one only is connected:

```
$ ls /dev/serial/by-id/*
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_DEVICE-NAME_XXXXXXXX-if00-port0
```

When the faulty one only is connected:

```
$ ls /dev/serial/by-id/*
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_DEVICE-NAME_-if00-port0
```

So is there a way to add a custom attribute to these devices, so I can differentiate them using udev rules?

Something like a command or a program to do

```
$ attribute_writing_binary /dev/tty_device_path "ATTRS{custom_attribute}=value"
```

Comment: no answers, just a question ... what's the complete output of the `udevadm` call (sans the `| grep`) for the faulty device?

Comment: @markp-fuso I took the output of the faulty device and the output of the working device and compared them: the first differences were related to the numbering of /dev/ttyUSB3 and 4 , and the ONLY other difference was the missing Serial Attribute.